# Problem with JavaScript files in Blazor component

Tags: javascript, blazor, .net-6.0

I use JavaScript file in Blazor component (Blazor server and .net 6).
as below:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/css/template/vendor/libs/bs-stepper/bs-stepper.js");
    }
}
```

When for the first time loading page everything is OK , but when I change page with nav and enter to another page (component) and after that again return to same as previous page , not working JavaScript codes.

What is the reason for this problem?

Comment: You are importing the module but you are not assigning it to any variable in order to use it.

Comment: Can you please explain more or correct my code example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use javascript libraries in blazor apps.

Add the script of the library at the end of `body` element in your `index.html` (or `_Layout.cshtml`)

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="css/template/vendor/libs/bs-stepper/bs-stepper.js"></script>
    ...
</body>
```

and the css at the end of `head` element

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template/vendor/libs/bs-stepper/bs-stepper.min.css">
    ...
</head>
```

Create a js file named e.g `stepperInteropHelper.js` in path `wwwroot/js` and inside add this function:

```
export function initStepper() {
    new Stepper(document.querySelector('.bs-stepper'));
}
```

Finally in your components that use a stepper:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="bs-stepper">
    ...
</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // import stepperInteropHelper.js module
            IJSObjectReference module = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./js/stepperInteropHelper.js");

            // call initStepper method from stepperInteropHelper.js
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("initStepper");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a large number of pages in the admin panel section of the site, each of which may have its own JavaScript files. Is it correct to add all these files in the _Layout.cshtml? Doesn't it increase the loading? Or js and css file related to any component be called withing itself ?

Comment: Yes, if you need all those JavaScript libraries you have to do it this way. But it would be better to try to minimize the usage of JavaScript libraries. We use Blazor to get rid of JavaScript. Most JavaScript libraries can be replaced with equivalent Blazor component libraries.